# Copy selection to clipboard automatically

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, copy-paste

I am looking for a program that can copy any selected text to the clipboard automatically. E.g. if I select some text in Safari or Eclipse, it should automatically copy it to the keyboard.

---

The Google Chrome extension [Auto Copy 3.0.3](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg) can do it in Google Chrome.

The application [PopClip](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39470/popclip) displays a popover menu which appears when some text is selected in any application but there doesn't seem to be any way to automatically copy it to the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into Automator or do you want a full fledged software application

Comment: @soulshined An Automator script would be good too. Is it possible to trigger an Automator script upon text selection? Or else do you have in mind sending Command+C every second or so?

Comment: you can do both, however the latter will be your more of a quick fix if you don't plan on using it outside of personal use. Triggering a script upon selection is doable but code heavy. You will have to invest time in to it. With applescript you write a quick script like this: tell application "System Events" keystroke "c" using command down end tell set theText to the clipboard and loop it indefinitely or run it every second as you suggested.

Comment: Franck disregard that. If you choose to loop it its going to override your last execution so say you copy selected text and run it again a second from now then if there is no text selected it will create a nil string even though you copied something 2 sec ago. I wouldn't suggest looping. Create if statements

Answer (score 1):

[Copy Clip](https://fiplab.com/apps/copyclip-for-mac) & it’ll sync with iOS devices, too.

Comment: Thanks. Does it copy any selected text to the clipboard automatically? ( I'm asking because I don't see it on the official website )

Comment: I tried Copy Clip and from what I can see it does not copy the selected text to the clipboard automatically.

Comment: My error, I meant to suggest CloudClip Manager (http://www.thinkbitz.com/cloudclip/). As long as it is running, it will keep a log of all copied text -- but this is saved to its own iOS app or Menulet not to the OS's clipboard. If you need everything saved to the built-in clipboard, you might search Lifehacker articles over the last 8 months or so as they've featured quite a few clipboard options.

Comment: This does not do what OP asked.